# TYPO3 replacement for "top margin" and "bottom margin" in LTS 7

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions, fluid-styled-content

With TYPO3 LTS 7 and up, top margin and bottom margin are not suported by Fluid styled content.

css styles content [image]

My users used a lot of those margins in 6.2 LTS

How can I do to make this working again (override TCA, extension, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can

1. install `Fluid Styled Content` *and* `CSS Styled Content`;
2. then *don't* add the static typoscript of `css styled content`.
3. modify the templates or partials of the `Fluid Styled Content` elements to use the new fields.

I don't know if this scenario has hidden drawbacks that I currently don't see.

Another scenario could be to use the `CSS Styled Content` also on version 7 and plan a migration to version 8 or 9 where they're used again, but the fields have become dropdown lists; plus, even the field names in database have changed: in version 6.2 they were `spaceBefore` and `spaceAfter` while since 8.7 they're called `space_before_class` and `space_after_class`.

As far as I know there are no conversion or upgrade tools between these fields.

See [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.6/Feature-79622-SpaceBeforeAndSpaceAfterClassForFluidStyledContent.html) and [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.6/Breaking-79622-SpaceBeforeAndSpaceAfterAdjustmentsForCSSStyledContent.html) for further details.

Comment: Are you saying that top margin and bottom margin are back in LTS 8? We plan to migrate to 7 and 8 in a few months

Comment: yes, but in a different way:
See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.6/Feature-79622-SpaceBeforeAndSpaceAfterClassForFluidStyledContent.html and 
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.6/Breaking-79622-SpaceBeforeAndSpaceAfterAdjustmentsForCSSStyledContent.html

Comment: I've enriched my answer.